# Checking DBMS versions in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am looking for a way to find all previous versions of the DBMS (Oracle is used). My point is to return versions of the DBMS that ever existed on the server and time when they were renewed in the following format:
[image: Table draft]

I found `sys.registry$history`, but not sure that this is exactly what I need.
Which functions is it better to use in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DBA_REGISTRY_SQLPATCH](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-F6D2BC12-606C-41FE-B9E8-F3702CD32F89.htm) should contain all of the information that you need.

```sql
  SELECT action_time,
         description,
         source_version,
         target_version
    FROM DBA_REGISTRY_SQLPATCH
   WHERE source_version <> target_version
ORDER BY action_time;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, my system responds with "table or view does not exist" for both `...FROM DBA_REGISTRY_SQLPATCH` and `...FROM SYS.DBA_REGISTRY_SQLPATCH`.

Comment: What version of Oracle Database are you on?

Comment: 11.2.0.3.0 - that's it.

Answer (score 2):

DBA_REGISTRY_PATCH was introduced in 12.1.0.2. This is the source of patching information you should use for Oracle Databases moving forwards. In 11.2 you could try selecting information from DBA_REGISTRY_HISTORY. Mike Dietrich has an [article](https://mikedietrichde.com/2016/11/30/dba_registry_history-vs-dba_registry_sqlpatch/) explaining all of this